# I need to write a program in C that will recursively solve a maze of X's and blank spaces

Tags: c, recursion, maze

the program must start at index [0][1] and completes the maze when it gets to index [7][7]. The program crashes when it reaches the "FindPath" function. I can't think of what I'm doing wrong, any info helps.

```
#include "Header.h"

int main(void) {

int x = 0, y = 1;

char maze[8][8] = {
{' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
{' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
{' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
{' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
{'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
{'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
{'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '},
{'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '},
};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        printf("%c ",maze[i][j]);
    }
        printf("\n");
}


FindPath(maze, x, y);

return 0;
}


#include "Header.h"

void FindPath(char maze[8][8], int x, int y) {

if (x == 7 & y == 7) {
    printf("Maze complete");

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%c ", maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
        return;
}
else {

    if (maze[x + 1][y] = ' ') {
        maze[x][y] = 'h';
        FindPath(maze, x + 1, y);
        return;
    }
    else if (maze[x - 1][y] = ' ') {
        maze[x][y] = 'h';
        FindPath(maze, x - 1, y);
        return;
    }
    else if (maze[x][y + 1] = ' ') {
        maze[x][y] = 'h';
        FindPath(maze, x, y + 1);
        return;
    }
    else if (maze[x][y - 1] = ' ') {
        maze[x][y] = 'h';
        FindPath(maze, x, y - 1);
        return;
    }
    else {
        printf("no path found");
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `if (maze[x + 1][y] = ' ')` - pretty sure you didn't mean to perform **assignment** there.  The `==` operator is for equivalence comparison. Repeated elsewhere in your code as well. So the "what I'm doing wrong" top-level would be not compiling with pedantic warnings enabled and fixing them upon inspection.

Comment: My guess is you're getting a stack overflow. Step through the program in the debugger and see where it's going.

Comment: @WhozCraig is right.  One common practice is to write your condition with the constant on the left side of the == so that the compiler will catch the issue if you use = instead of ==.  I.e., `if (' ' = maze[x + 1][y])`

Comment: I think index range checking is  necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is simpler than you're making it.

Primary issue with your approach: `FindPath()` needs to work on a trial and error basis -- you don't have any strategy for allowing it to succeed and/or fail and signal such to it's caller, nor undo it's wrong assumptions.

Issues with your code: folks have already mentioned `=` vs. `==` but you also use `&` when you mean `&&`; your code indentation, or SO code posting, needs work; you should strive to avoid numbers in your code so you can swap out the maze later; your lower level routines should return results, not print -- your higher level routines should get back those results and decide what to print; lots of redundant code -- move duplicated statements up a level; as others have mentioned, you need limit checking as expressions like `maze[x - 1][y]` can encroach on memory you didn't allocate if `x` is zero.

Below is a rework of your codes along the lines above and with some style changes.  It solves the one maze you provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define WIDTH (8)
#define HEIGHT (8)

void printMaze(char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
                    printf("%c ", maze[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

bool findPath(char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int x, int y) {

    maze[x][y] = 'h';

    if (x == WIDTH - 1 && y == HEIGHT - 1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (x + 1 < WIDTH && maze[x + 1][y] == ' ') {
        if (findPath(maze, x + 1, y)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (x - 1 >= 0 && maze[x - 1][y] == ' ') {
        if (findPath(maze, x - 1, y)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (y + 1 < HEIGHT && maze[x][y + 1] == ' ') {
        if (findPath(maze, x, y + 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (y - 1 >= 0 && maze[x][y - 1] == ' ') {
        if (findPath(maze, x, y - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    maze[x][y] = ' ';

    return false;
}

int main(void) {

    char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {
        {' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
        {' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
        {' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
        {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
        {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x'},
        {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
        {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '},
        {'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '},
    };

    printMaze(maze);

    if (findPath(maze, 0, 1)) {
        printf("Maze completed!\n");
        printMaze(maze);
    } else {
        printf("No path found!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
    x x x x x x 
  x x x x x x x 
  x x x x x x x 
          x x x 
x x x x   x x x 
x x x x         
x x x x x x x   
x x x x x x x   
Maze completed!
h h x x x x x x 
h x x x x x x x 
h x x x x x x x 
h h h h h x x x 
x x x x h x x x 
x x x x h h h h 
x x x x x x x h 
x x x x x x x h 
>
```